# How to write Razor Pages unit tests in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, razor-pages

I'm using the MVVM pattern on ASP.NET. I want to know how to write Razor Pages unit tests in ASP.NET Core using xUnit, especially for a POST request.

Comment: none of those things is appropriate for unit testing.

Comment: Check the Microsoft official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: yap, Saw it but is there any clear way to do the test for a post request?